# Cannot have UI updated when data received through socket.io in Angular

Tags: angular, socket.io

In my sample application I have the web client connecting to the socket.io server, this part is working fine. The data sent by the server (over the websocket) are correctly received by the client but... when variables are changed, they are not reflected back in the UI:

This is my basic code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private socket: any;
  public total: number = 0;

  constructor() {
    this.socket = io('');

    // Update scores when a new vote is received
    this.socket.on('scores', function (json) {

      // Extract number of votes for each item (a / b)
      let data = JSON.parse(json);
      let a = parseInt(data["a"] || 0);
      let b = parseInt(data["b"] || 0);

      // Setting this prop to indicate the total number of votes
      this.total = a + b;       // <== this is not updated in the html vue
      ...
    });
  }
}
```

In the html, I just have something similar to:

```
<div id="result">
      <span *ngIf="total == 0">No votes yet</span>
      <span *ngIf="total == 1">{{total}} vote</span>
      <span *ngIf="total >= 2">{{total}} votes</span>
    </div>
```

Any hint what I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly `this.total` is not the component's property because it's in a function scope. Instead, you should be using an arrow function to point correct this :

```
this.socket.on('scores',  (json) => { // <<--

      // Extract number of votes for each item (a / b)
      let data = JSON.parse(json);
      let a = parseInt(data["a"] || 0);
      let b = parseInt(data["b"] || 0);

      // Setting this prop to indicate the total number of votes
      this.total = a + b;       // <== this should be updated in the HTML now
      ...
    });
```

Comment: Wow !! Thanks a lot, you saved my night :)